# Issues installing IBM Process Designer

Tags: ibm-bpm

Respected Sir/Madam,

I am trying to install IBM Process Designer, but getting below errors.

ERROR: The Installation Manager's registry information is inconsistent with its installation information.

**ERROR: The registry information at "HKLM\SOFTWARE\IBM\Installation Manager" indicates that the Installation Manager is not installed. However, the information at the "C:\ProgramData\IBM\Installation Manager" data location indicates that Installation Manager 1.7.2 (internal version: 1.7.2000.20140227_0303) is installed at location "C:\Program Files\IBM\InstallationManager\eclipse".**

00:00.76 ERROR [main] com.ibm.cic.agent.core.application.HeadlessApplication run The Installation Manager's registry information is inconsistent with its installation information. The registry information at "HKLM\SOFTWARE\IBM\Installation Manager" indicates that the Installation Manager is not installed. However, the information at the "C:\ProgramData\IBM\Installation Manager" data location indicates that Installation Manager 1.7.2 (internal version: 1.7.2000.20140227_0303) is installed at location "C:\Program Files\IBM\InstallationManager\eclipse".

Resolution provided by IBM at below url http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21639541 says,

" Run IBM Installation Manager directly; do not use the LaunchPad. From the Windows Start menu, select All Programs ->IBM Installation Manager > IBM Installation Manager. When Installation Manager starts, click Install, ensure all products are selected, and click Next to start the typical installation. "

But when I start the installation manager from Windows Start menu , it does not provide me the option to install IBM Process Designer at all.

Please find error logs "" attached, which come when I try to install IBM Process Designer from its setup "installProcessDesigner_admin".

I have installed Process center v8.5 successfully but not the way suggested. I have first installed db2 separately( used same db2 setup which came inside IBM BPM 8.5 PACKAGE ) and then installed Process center v8.5 using launchpad.exe , as it was giving db related errors when I was trying to install directly from launchpad.exe in BPM package I think IBM installation manager got installed when I was installing IBM BPM V8.5.

Please guide
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error says Installation Manager has been already installed in different location.

I would suggest to open Installation Manager from Start, then

In Installation Manager, File - > Preferences -> Add repository.config

1. if 32 bit operating system - repository.config location (C:\IBM_Process_Designer\IM)
2. if 64 bit operating system - repository.config location (C:\IBM_Process_Designer\IM64)